# Basic C, incorrect output

Tags: c, arrays

English isn't my native language, and I actually speak it very bad, so I can't give a explanation about the program.

But here is an example output:

```
Insert the 1st number: 1234                                                                                                                                                                   
Insert the 2nd number: 1111                                                                                                                                                                   
Select an operation (1=addition; 2=subtraction; 3=multiplication; 4=division): 1                                                                                                              
|0||0||0||0||0||0||1||2||3||4|                                                                                                                                                                
+                                                                                                                                                                                             
|0||0||0||0||0||0||1||1||1||1|                                                                                                                                                                
=                                                                                                                                                                                             
|0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||0||2||3||4||0|
```

The last position is wrong, it should be 5.

I think it's simple to solve it, for a more experienced programmer.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int n[10], n2[10], num, nun, i=9, j=9, sv=0, on, res[4][20], opc[4][20];
main(){
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        for (j=0; j<4; j++){
            opc[j][i] = 0;
            res[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<10; j++){
        n[j] = 0;
        n2[j] = 0;
    }
    i=9; j=9;
    printf("Insert the 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    sv = num;
    while (num != 0){
        n[i] = num%10;
        num = num/10; 
        i--;
    }
    num = sv;
    printf("Insert the 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d", &nun);
    sv = nun;
    while (nun != 0){
        n2[j] = nun%10;
        nun = nun/10; 
        j--;
    }
    nun = sv;
    printf("Select an operation (1=addition; 2=subtraction; 3=multiplication; 4=division): ");
    scanf("%d", &on);
    while((on>4)||(on<0)){
        printf("Try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &on);
    }
    if (on==1){
        for (i=9; i>=0; i--){
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9){
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
            }
            if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) > 9){
                opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])-10;
                opc[1][9+i] = (n[i] + n2[i])/10;
            }
        }
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++){
            printf("|%d|", n[i]);
        }
        printf("\n+\n");
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++){
            printf("|%d|", n2[i]);
        }
        printf("\n=\n");
        for (i=0; i<=19; i++){
            printf("|%d|", opc[1][i]);
        }           
    }
}
```

And sorry for my English.

Comment: Don't worry, perfect English is not required on StackOverflow, or I myself would be pretty lost. But even if your English would be improvable, you have to explain more about the (desired) logic of your program. Can you describe a rule behind the desired output? What do the numbers mean? If you can get the idea across in any quality of English, you can trust the users here to either just answer or probably kindly edit your question to improve the English.

Comment: Consider using comments inside your code as an intuitive way (for a programmer) to clarify what you are thinking, what you hope/think to achieve with each line.

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). So compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....), improve your code to get no warnings, then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. But StackOverflow is not a fix-my-code or do-my-work site.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well I'll try explain it. There is two numbers, entered by the user, and each digit of this number will be put in each position of the array, (num -> n), (nun -> n2). If the number entered was 560, the 8th pos of this array will be 5, the 8th, 6 and the 9th, 0. After it, the user will choice a operation to do with this numbers, (+,-,* or /), but I need to make that just using the numbers stored in the array. When doing the addiction, I realized that error, now I can't go forward.

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Also, read the documentation of every function you use, notably of [standard I/O functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Notice that [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns a value that your code should test, and that [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) outputs to a *buffered* `stdout` (often line-buffered). You'll better end your `printf` format control strings with `\n` and/or use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

Comment: I'm don't sayin' "Do my work", It's just a error that I'm facin', and I can't see why.

Comment: I think you can describe your goal as writing a simple calculator, with handwritten digit by digit math. I speculate that the reason for this is educational.

Comment: Yep, basically it

Comment: So **learn how to debug programs** (it is a basic skill required of every developer). A previous comment of mine gave links and hints about that. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for useful insights

Comment: No, isn't a homework, It's a friend's challenge, I'm trying to do it for improvement purposes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I'll check these links

Comment: Learning to debug is a constructive recommendation. The links from another comment are good. Here is an additional one for the case that you are lost in complexity: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for all, I have too much to learn

Comment: @RacionalMente make it a priority to learn how to use your debugger.   Don't try to write any more code until you have some of those essential skills that are required to get it working correctly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The successive `if` block of this `if` block:

```
        if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9){
            opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
        }
```

should be in `else` block because in the first `if` block, if condition evaluates to true, you are modifying `opc[1][10+i]` and in successive `if` block checking the same condition for `> 9` with modified value of `opc[1][10+i]`.
If the condition `((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9)` evaluate to false then only control should go to this `if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) > 9)` block but if it evaluates to true then the control should not go to next `if` block.

In fact, you don't need to do this check - `((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) > 9)`. Just put the statements of second `if` block in `else` of first, like this:

```
        if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9){
            opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
        } else {
            opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])-10;
            opc[1][9+i] = (n[i] + n2[i])/10;
        }
```

But this still may not give the correct output, for e.g for input `55` and `45` this doesn't work. The reason is that the carry forward `opc[1][9+i]` is not handled properly in the successive iterations of `for` loop. Thanks user3386109 for pointing this out. You can do:

```
        if ((n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i]) <= 9){
            opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i]);
        } else {
            opc[1][9+i] = (n[i] + n2[i] + opc[1][10+i])/10;
            opc[1][10+i] += (n[i] + n2[i])-10;
        }
```

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for pointing it out. I have modified the post.

Comment: Thanks so much, You helped me a lot